# How to run script from within Mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sqlyog

I have a SQL script to distribute to others to run from a MySQL IDE, not from a MySQL command prompt.

I want the user to load the script into a window of workbench (or another IDE like sqlyog) and just run the script, which inserts records based on variables, for example:

```
SELECT value FROM mytable WHERE key = "mykey" into @columnid;

INSERT INTO mytable (col2,col3) VALUES (
@columnid,
'testvalue'
)
```

We all have MySQL Workbench installed but I don't see a way to do this from workbench.

Is there a way to run a script (that is in an editor window) from workbench (or any other MySQL IDE) the way you can run scripts from other database IDE's like Toad or SQL Server Management Studo?

Comment: File > Open SQL Script ?

Comment: You'll need to specify a default database if you aren't using a database prefix.  (Right click on Database, set as default, or something of the likes)

Answer (score 26):

There are two *different* methods:

1. ***File -> Open SQL Script***: This simply loads the file contents into a new SQL query tab in the SQL editor. From here, execute the query exactly like you would if you typed it in.
2. ***File -> Run SQL Script***: This opens the SQL script in its own "Run SQL Script" wizard that includes a [Run] button to execute the query. This only displays part of the query, but does allow the user to override the selected schema and character set. **Note:** *This feature was added in Workbench 6.2.*

I suspect you want the simpler "Run SQL Script".

Comment: For very long scripts (e.g. restoring from backup) I think the Run SQL Script option is preferable as it doesn't load the entire script.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to go to the `File` option and then click `Open SQL Script`.

You can refer: [SQL Query Window Toolbar](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-toolbar.html) and a [small video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHDz7uWjCyU)

Answer (score 3):

After open the Mysql workbench ,Just follow these steps,

1. start the server

> server -> server status -> start server

2. create the relevant database

> navigator(in left side) -> schemas -> (right click) new schema -> your
>   new db name ->ok

3. set the new db as default schema

> right click the new db name -> set as default schema

4. Run the query

> file-> open a sql script -> Open relevant script -> execute it

5. Finish

Answer (score 1):

Most RDMS IDE tools have a way to open a SQL script from a menu item.

In Workbench, it's File > Open SQL Script... like Maximus2012 wrote.

In HeidiSQL, it's File > Load SQL File ...